# Backbone view with template not firing events

Tags: javascript, events, templates, backbone.js

I'm having some problems with my view handling it's events. They simply don't fire.
The view has it's html from a template that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="intro-slide-template">
  <div class="slide intro" id="intro-slide">
    <a href="#" class="startpresentation" id="start-btn">
      <%= startpresentation %>
    </a>
  </div>
</script>
```

So far so good.
The view code itself look's like this:

```
  /* ********* Slide View  *********  */
    window.IntroSlideView = Backbone.View.extend({           
        initialize: function(){             
            this.template = _.template($("#intro-slide-template").html());          
        },  
        render: function(){     
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));             
        },
        events: {
            "click #start-btn": "clickHandler"
        },
        clickHandler: function() {
            console.log("IntroSlideView     ::      clickHandler");
        }           
    });
```

This is how I render the slide to the main app's view:

```
/* ********* App View  *********  */
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#content"),
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');      

        //render 
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){                     
        this.el.innerHTML = "";     
        var slide = this.model.get("currentSlide");
        slide.render();             
        this.el.innerHTML = slide.el.innerHTML;
    }   
});
```

The view is getting rendered to the screen perfectly, and it works just like it should.
But the click event is not firing.

When I inspect the slide view object, I can see that it do haves el object with the right HTML in it, including the button that has to fire a click event.

And when I log the view's events, I see that they are set:

```
Object
click #start-btn: "clickHandler"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: I think you are copying the innerHTML from the slide view to the app view, but not the event handlers. Do you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this pattern](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#sub_views)

```
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.slide = new window.IntroSlideView({ el: this.$(".slide") });

    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: I have set the element and now it fires the event. But I have two views with this model and now I fire twice while pressing just a single time. How can I disable an other view with the same event listeners?

Comment: Not sure why, but slide.undelegateEvents(); in the main app view did the trick, do you have any ideas why this works?

Comment: Perhaps you were loading the IntroSlideView twice on the same el?

Comment: I´m loading two different slideviews instances on the same el. Shouldnt they only listen to their own #start-btn click?

Comment: The events are delegated to the views root el, so if both views are using the same el, they will both have that event handler bound.

Comment: Seems logic, but how to bind an event click to an element within the slide template?